# How can I install the acme editor/shell/user interface on Ubuntu?

Tags: text-editor

[acme](http://acme.cat-v.org/) is a text editor, development environment and textual-user-interface platform developed by Rob Pike for the Plan 9 operating system.

According to [its website](http://acme.cat-v.org/) there are several ways to get acme, including the plan9ports package and the acme-sac stand alone complex.

So what's the easiest way to get acme running on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install acme on Ubuntu is to install the acme-sac stand alone version.

1) Go to the [acme-sac page on Google code](https://code.google.com/p/acme-sac/downloads/list?q=Ubuntu) and download the latest deb-package for Ubuntu.

2) Double click on the filename to start GDebi and install.